# Can you launch a code or a method in separate process?

Tags: c#, process

I have a function that I want to launch it in a new process .

Like

```
public void test(){}
Process.start(test());
```

Like same thing with threads but not on the same process.

Or it's impossible we can run in new process an exe files ?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?  There may be a better solution to the general problem than what you're asking.

Comment: Depeds on why you want it. Are you wanting to be able to terminate this second process via something like Task Manager or are you wanting separate static variables. The 2nd option is doable via AppDomains, the first will be harder to do. EDIT: also to extend on what Matthew said, don't fall in to a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) explain to us the problem you are trying to solve, not the problem you are having with the solution you came up with.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i want to calculate the time cpu for each code separatly in differente process.

I use app domain a launch them in differente thread but when i try to calculate the time cpu i use just GetCurrentProcess don't want to use StopWatch.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the actual answer, but I would try and find another way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to do.

However, you can use *DLL Injection* to execute code in another process, although this would be a fairly large amount of work.

See below:
[Link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wYTLAAHgjk)
[Link 2 (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-Net-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes)

Comment: The code which u sent me is not in c# and also don't need to inject Dll otherwise i can just lanch .exe in other process but i want to run just a method to other process like if i'm runing it in other thread which is simple but i want it in separate process.

Comment: I need more information, I find it difficult to understand what you are writing.  Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your code itself is an executable, you can extend it to analyze command-line parameters and run your specific function. I.e. you can use Process.start to run a second instance of your application with a parameter which will tell the second instance, which function to execute.